# Meteor - How to automatically remove a single item from a collection after a specific time period from within a server side method?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, methods, collections, timer

I wrote a click. event which calls a method. This method pushes single items (InfoId) into the collection called userManagement. So these items are assigned to that user.

eventhandler:

```
Template.available.events({
"click .push": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var InfoId = this.InfoId;
    Meteor.call('pushInfo', InfoId);
}, });
```

And the method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'pushInfo': function(InfoId) {
    if (this.userId) {
      userManagement.update({
          '_id': this.userId
        }, {
          $push: {
            'activeInfos': InfoId
          }
        } 
      );
    }
  }
});
```

However, now I need to automatically remove exactly this previously added single item (InfoId) from 'activeInfos' after a specific time period e. g. three months.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for doing this you can use cronjob 
just install it using  `meteor add percolate:synced-cron`

in cron you need to do two things one is add a task to cron, second is start our cron.

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'your cron name',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 2 hours');
  },
  job: function() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
});
```

here schedule: is use to set time and in Job: we will add code which we want to run after a time we added in schedule.

after this start your cron. for this add this

```
SyncedCron.start();
```

for more info check this link https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron .

for schedule timing read this http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#overview

i hope this will help

Comment: Many thanks for this approach. I am reading and trying to understand all of this on GitHub right now to implement Cronjob. Though, do you know how I could actually run this within a server side method? I have written a userManagement.update function with a $pull code in a method to remove a single item (InfoId) from a user. This works. But I don´t know how to use the SyncedCron.add ({...}) with that? Or can I just write SyncedCron.add({ with that $pull function}) on the server and start the SyncedCron.start() from within the click. event?

Comment: we use cron job on server side. just put your cron code inside Meteor.startup() in server side which is a kind of main function or you can create separate file and import in main file on server. SyncedCron run automatically when it see start() function of it and execute the job function on time we specified. This is helpfull in case when we want to repeat a function after specified time. you should put userManagement.update query inside job function.

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer correct by clicking right sign on my answer if my answer helped you somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach to problems like this is to use a [mongo TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) to have mongo remove documents automatically. TTL indexes only work on documents (not on sub documents) so if you wanted to go down that route, you'd need to separate out `activeInfos` into a separate collection, and use the aggregation pipeline's `$lookup` stage during finds to recreate your original documents.

`db.active_infos.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: appropriateNumberOfSeconds } )`